# How to redirect to another webpage when a specific button is pressed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I made 2 buttons which are update and logout, problem is how do I redirect user when I one of the button is pressed(e.g logout button will redirect user to logout.php) using javascript

```
<div align="right" class="button1">
        <span><button>Update</button></span>
        <span><button>Logout</button></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Start by reading up on DOM Events: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp

Comment: this sounds like a job for link (a) tags

Comment: you can do something like ```<button onClick="location.href='logout.php'">logout</button>```

Comment: and you tried nothing out? give the button an id, for example `logoutButton` and then do `document.getElementById('logoutButton').addEventListener('click', function() { window.location.href = '/logout.php'}`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div align="right" class="button1">
        <span><button>Update</button></span>
        <span><button onClick="location.href='logout.php'">Logout</button></span>
</div>
```